# Android Splash screen animation - import Splash Animated Vector Drawable (AVD) XML example to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

How do I import and use the **AVD XML file** from the **example starter kit** provided by google to Android Studio which can be downloaded here:

https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen#splash-screen-resources

Answer (score 1):

Just copy-paste the `news_avd_v02.xml` file into your drawable directory, then open it with double click.
Now, you'll see the comment on top which you will have to remove, otherwise it will show you the error.

After doing so, you'll see 3 buttons at the bottom of the `avd preview`. Simply check how the animation will look by hitting the `Play` button in the middle.